# AWS EC2 reboot - Startup script is not working with pm2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, pm2

Whenever EC2 reboot is happened, I wanted to start the nginx service along with several other node js application.

I have created `rc.local`.

I have added below line of code in that:

```
#/etc/startup_script.sh
#actual path to your script file.
/usr/bin/bash /etc/startup_script.sh &
exit 0
```

startup_script.sh:

```
sudo systemctl start nginx.service

#start pm2 services
pm2 start npm --name node_server1
pm2 start npm --name node_server2
pm2 start npm --name node_server3
pm2 start npm --name node_server4

pm2 save
```

Getting below error

```
-- Reboot --
Jul 25 14:30:00 ip-10-192-3-238 systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
Jul 25 14:30:00 ip-10-192-3-238 systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jul 25 14:30:00 ip-10-192-3-238 systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 25 14:30:00 ip-10-192-3-238 systemd[1]: Failed to start /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download that service into your linux machine first:

```
sudo yum install nginx -y
```